# SSRS scheduled reports not executing -

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We have a number of reports scheduled to run throughout the week. Some reports are also setup as Agent Job reports and use SP_send_dbmail to the send the report in HTML format. For the last week or so, multiple reports have failed to send, while others are going through in the same day. IT's been an intermitten issue as some days all reports seem to go through, but i don't have any alerts to notify me of failed reports.

I looked through the log files for the reportserver from \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles ;
This error messages comes up frequently:

```
ERROR: PollingMaintenance: Restarting maintenance thread for the following exception:  This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InstrumentedSqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass3d.<GetString>b__3c()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SqlBoundaryWithReturn`1.Invoke(Method m)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.EventQueueWorker.GetNextQueueItem(IDataRecord record)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.QueuePollWorker.ProcessData(IDataReader reader)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.DBPoll.PollingFunction()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.DBPoll.PollingMaintenance().
library!WindowsService_827!8d4!07/10/2015-05:54:19:: i INFO: PollingMaintenance: Polling cycle completed.
```

Other than that, i'm not seeing any useful info in the ExecutionLogStorage table under LastStatus ( just says rsProcessAborted on a few records).

I also tried running this query to look for failed reports, but the ones that failed today aren't coming up:

```
SELECT
    c.Name AS [ReportName],
    sb.[Description] AS [SubscriptionDescription],
    sb.DeliveryExtension AS [DeliveryType],
    sb.LastStatus AS [LastRunStatus],
    sb.LastRunTime AS [LastRunTime],
    c.Path AS [ReportPath],
    'http://sql-server/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath='+REPLACE(REPLACE(C.[Path],'/','%2f'),' ','+')+'&SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab&ViewMode=List&SelectedSubTabId=SubscriptionsTab' AS [SubscriptionLink],
    sc.ScheduleID AS [SQLAgentJobName],
    sb.SubscriptionID
FROM
    ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule AS RS
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Schedule sc ON rs.ScheduleID = sc.ScheduleID
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sb ON rs.SubscriptionID = sb.SubscriptionID
    INNER JOIN ReportServer.dbo.[Catalog] c ON rs.ReportID = c.ItemID AND sb.Report_OID = c.ItemID
WHERE
    (sb.LastStatus LIKE 'Failure%' OR sb.LastStatus LIKE 'Error%' OR sb.LastStatus LIKE '%not valid%')
    order by lastruntime asc
```

Comment: See if anything here helps -https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52bb8568-a5be-4899-a767-5b52131f01a9/ms-sql-20008-ssrs-error?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I checked the linked in the replies on that thread but it doesn't seem relevant to my issue. The only comminality is the the error that mentions "This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database", bu that error only comes up a few times compared to the other 1 i posted above. A number of reports with multiple subscriptions was scheduled to send today at 10:09AM, but none of them went through; I checked the Agent job history for that job and it shows succeeded...

Comment: I'm running simple batch file to record any dropped packets when pinging...I'm testing it from both my network and the network where our SQL server is hosted ( Pinging SQL from my computer and Pinging our mail server from SQL) Will update if this brings anything up.

Comment: @samalkobi - What are the parameters of the report, which values do you pass to it in your subscription?

Comment: Did you check the junk mail of the recipient? Since the email has embedded HTML this may be marked as junk.

Comment: I don't know exactly how many of the reports use parameters, but usually therey're simple values for a given column. I didn't consider looking at any of the reports as a cause since we've had the same reports in place for longer than i've worked here...As an update, i added a subscription to report for myself to send this morning; In the Agent Job history it shows it succeeded, but 0 rows sent and 0sec duration....I run the report in IE and i get a set of results...

Comment: Most of the reports send the results in an Excel attachment; We haven't had any issues with normal e-mail sent from Outlook at all anytime recently that would correlate with this. Does anyone have any suggestion as to what to look for in logs to determine if this a mail server issue (DBMail is configured to send through our SMTP Server running HmailServer), SQL Agent or SSRS? . Also, those Agent Job reports that SP_Send_DBmail, those seem to work and i'm getting results for some of those...

Comment: So the issue seemed to stem from the EVents table, where a hole bunch of processes were left untouched and i think SQL just kept trying to re-run them after they timed out. I got help from a support rep at our cloud hosting site and he cleared was able to find more details pertaining to the issue. These articles cover it fairly well. Mainly the part about the orphaned events. I didn't get to see exactly how it was done but it gave me more info on how to read the RS logfile and how to identify those events so i will be reviewing those for learning purposes.

Comment: [One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2009/01/13/diagnosing-and-troubleshooting-subscriptions.aspx),[two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deanka/archive/2010/02/16/troubleshooting-subscriptions-part-ii-using-the-report-services-trace-log-file.aspx),[Three](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/02/02/why-aren-t-my-subscriptions-working.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now resolved;
This required more digging into the events table and we found an Agent job that was scheduled to update an old subscription on a report. Said report was causing issues over month ago, and i deleted the subscription and created a new report using the same query. The job updating the report seemed to be queuing events in the Events table, and they kept timing out as there was no subscription for that report. We cleared out those events the other day and only a few were remaining, but all reports have been going out on schedule. The links i posted in my last comment above cover the main areas that pointed us in the right direction.